# Linking online network server between software and application without web

Tags: ios, testing, web, networking, server

I'm trying to make my network server online and link it to a system and an application that I designed. However I don't want to make a website to upload the server to. Is this possible? Can I link my server directly to my software and my application via the internet? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to servers with out the world wide web.
Their is for example the [Gropher protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gopher_(protocol)).
Most likely this is not what you are looking for.

If you want to reach your server from *the outside* you need a public IP address. Your internet provider has to give you one. You could get around this, if you know someone with a public IP who accepts to forward your traffic.

Comment: "_Your internet provider has to give you one._" Actually, more and more ISPs are turning to CGN for residential users, giving people Shared or Private addresses, saving its public addresses for businesses willing to pay for the privilege of having a public address.